# Facebook messenger checkbox plugin: not able to send message to user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

I am trying to setup facebook messenger checkbox plugin to subscribe users to receive auto response when they subscribe.

So far I am able to render checkbox plugin using app_id and page_id with user_ref parameter as described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/checkbox-plugin#implementation

I can optin and it receives confirmation response in subscribed event (messenger_checkbox) and app webhook. I receive optin object with user_ref in the webhook post data. I think upto this point its working correctly.

Now, when I try to send message to subscribed user with user_ref received in confirmation response, I get error 
`{"error":{"message":"(#100) No matching user found","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":2018001,"fbtrace_id":"CqlbK97gibd"}}`

My curl request is:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient": {
    "user_ref": "unique_user9898"
  }, 
  "message": {
    "text":"hello, world!"
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me/messages?access_token=XXXXXXXXXX_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN_XXXXXXXXXX"`

I am getting page access token from FB graph api explorer.
[image]

I also double checked `Send/Receive API` section [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/faq#faq_1769559379978656)

I hope I was able to explain the issue.

Comment: Sorry, did silly mistake. I was using different app_id in my code and getting page_access_token. Need suggestion. should I delete this question?

Comment: Answer your own question